# validate method within a class

Tags: python, validation, class, methods

I am creating a class called Conversation as part of a larger code and want to make sure the fields the user enters in are valid (in the case that they're not valid I want to raise a Value Error), but my is_valid method isn't working when I run the program:

class Conversation:

```
def __init__(self, members, size_limit, backup_policy, cloud_account_prefix='./'):
    if not self.is_valid():
        raise ValueError
    self.members = members
    self.size_limit = size_limit
    self.backup_policy = backup_policy
    self.cloud_account_prefix = cloud_account_prefix
    self.backup_count = 0
    self.size_count = 0
    self.messages = []

def is_valid(self, members, size_limit, backup_policy, cloud_account_prefix):
    if self.members < 2:
        return False
    if self.size_limit <= 10:
        return False
    if not path_ok(self.cloud_account_prefix):
        return False
    if self.backup_policy < 1:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not working? Any error? Are you calling it somewhere?

Comment: remove 'self.' in your is_valid function. At this moment there are not yet defined. Use the arguments directly instead. eg: "if members <2:"

Comment: Why don't you validate your attributes on assignment using properties? Also you should give better feedback; why not make the validation throw the error that actually says *which value and why*? "There was a ValueError" doesn't tell me anything, but e.g. "you must specify at least two members" is useful information.

Comment: By "not working" I mean it's allowing me to enter numbers in that don't fit with the validation criteria I set up.

Comment: Really? Because given what you post I'd expect "not working" to mean "throws errors", as you aren't passing the required arguments. Please give a [mcve] that clarifies the issue.

Answer (score 2):

1. You are calling `is_valid` before any initialization is done so any call to `self.something` inside it will result with `AttribueError`.
2. `is_valid` expects 4 arguments yet you call it with 0.

Your code should be

```
class Conversation:
    def __init__(self, members, size_limit, backup_policy, cloud_account_prefix='./'):

        self.members = members
        self.size_limit = size_limit
        self.backup_policy = backup_policy
        self.cloud_account_prefix = cloud_account_prefix
        self.backup_count = 0
        self.size_count = 0
        self.messages = []
        if not self.is_valid():
            raise ValueError

    def is_valid(self):
        if self.members < 2:
            return False
        if self.size_limit <= 10:
            return False
        if not path_ok(self.cloud_account_prefix):
            return False
        if self.backup_policy < 1:
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

Another approach could be to pass all the arguments from `__init__` to `is_valid` to verify they are valid before bothering to initialize the instance attributes:

```
class Conversation:
    def __init__(self, members, size_limit, backup_policy, cloud_account_prefix='./'):
        if not self.is_valid(members, size_limit, backup_policy, cloud_account_prefix):
            raise ValueError
        self.members = members
        self.size_limit = size_limit
        self.backup_policy = backup_policy
        self.cloud_account_prefix = cloud_account_prefix
        self.backup_count = 0
        self.size_count = 0
        self.messages = []

    def is_valid(self, members, size_limit, backup_policy, cloud_account_prefix):
        if members < 2:
            return False
        if size_limit <= 10:
            return False
        if not path_ok(cloud_account_prefix):
            return False
        if backup_policy < 1:
            return False
        else:
            return True
```